# Firefox - how to get selected text when using double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, selection, contenteditable

I created a contentEditable div with a text portion and a link. Double clicking the link will select the link text.

```
<div contentEditable="true">
   This is a text and <a href="http://www.google.com">This_is_a_link</a>
</div>
```

Afterwards calling document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer will return the div:

```
// => <div contenteditable="true">
```

Instead of the link. I cannot find a way to find which part of the div is selected.

See this jsfiddle (double click the "This_is_a_link" and there will be a console log with startContainer):
http://jsfiddle.net/UExsS/1/

(Obligatory JS code from the fiddle)

```
$(function(){
    $('a').dblclick(function(e) {

        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0));
        }, 500);

    });
});
```

Note, that Chrome has the correct behavior, and running the above jsfiddle in Chrome will give textElement for startContainer.

Has anyone run into this issue? did you find a workaround?

Comment: It's not impossible to get the selected text in Firefox. The range you've got from the selection tells you precisely where its boundaries are.

Comment: I got startOffset = 0, endOffset = 0. have you tried it? I am using Firefox 24

Comment: In your jsFiddle in Firefox 24 I get `startOffset` 1 and `endOffset` 2, with `startContainer` and `endContainer` both referring to the `<div>`. This is what I'd expect.

Comment: I did get 1 and 2 before. What is the 1 and 2 mean?

Comment: For each boundary (start and end), if the container is an element rather than a text node then the offset is the number of child nodes within the container that precede the boundary. In your example, the start of the selection range in Firefox comes after one child of the `<div>` (i.e. immediately after the `"  This is a text and "` text node) and the end comes after two children (i.e. immediately after the `<a>` element).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think its a bug of Firefox, just a different kind of implementation. When you double click the link, Firefox selects not only the text, but the whole a-tag, so the parent node of the selection is correctly set to the div container.

I added these few lines of code to your fiddle to proof that point:

```
var linknode = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.childNodes[1];
console.log(linknode);        
console.log(window.getSelection().containsNode(linknode, false));
```

Forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XZ6vc/

When you run it, you'll see in the javascript console that *linknode* contains your link, and the check if the link is fully contained in the selection returns true.

This is also one possible solution to the problem, albeit not ideal one. Iterate over all the links in your contenteditable and check if one of them is fully contained in the selection.

Though one word of advice: Don't reinvent the wheel if you don't have to ;-) There's quite possibly some libraries / frameworks out there that fit your needs.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks! and I am not aware of other libraries other than a full fledged WYSIWYG editors.

Comment: window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents() and window.getSelection.getRangeAt(0).toString() in Firefox will give you *more* text than is visibly selected. Regardless of whether or not the correct bounds are set on the range object, that certainly seems very bug-like. In Chrome, either option gives you exactly the content of the selection as visible on screen.

Comment: Additionally, it works identically to Chrome if you manually select a specific range, as opposed to using double-click to select. I.e., the visual effect, and what you get if you copy-paste with Ctrl-C or whatever, is the same between double-click and manual drag-to-select in Firefox and either option in Chrome, but what you get out of the Range object is *different* when double-click selecting in Firefox from any of those other cases.