# Mozilla/Chrome get windowSelection parentNode different on double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, mozilla

I need to get selected text html element on double click

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
console.log(  selection.getRangeAt(0).startContainer.parentNode.tagName  )
```

Its perfectly working in chrome but in mozila result is **parentNode.parentNode.tagName**

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/wtzrev7n/)

*I tried with this solution but no luck*
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19235797/1312610

Comment: I see no difference between the behavior in Google Chrome 57.0.2987.98 and Mozilla Firefox 52.0 (32-bit).

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234988/firefox-how-to-get-selected-text-when-using-double-click?noredirect=1&lq=1 ?

Comment: PLz help me , I am really got stuck , That solution is not good - I have tried already

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in Mozilla Firefox 52.0 (32-bit).
[image]

Comment: click and select whole text of single line

Comment: If I select the entire blue span, I still see SPAN at the bottom. Even if I also select a trailing space _after_ the blue span, I still get SPAN at the bottom. Only if I also select a space before the blue frame do I see DIV. [/Firefox]